# How do I change the description of input's displayed for an operation defined using a MXBean

Tags: java, annotations, jmx, jconsole

I'm using a MXBean to instrument a certain feature, and I have a method that takes in 3 input arguments.

By default, on the jconsole, the arguments are displayed as p1, p2, p3 etc. I have @params describing each parameter. How do I make jConsole use those?

```
public class Sample implements SampleMXBean {

    /**
     * method 1
     *
     * @param input1 Input One
     * @param input2 Input Two
     */
     public void getInput(int input1, int input2) {
       ...
       ...
     }
}
```

I have registered the above MXBean , and when I launch, the panel for this operation, I get a button with "getInput" as the text, and 2 text boxes with names as p1 and p2, instead of "Input One" and "Input Two".

Are there any annotations that I need to use to achieve this?
(Btw I'm using jdk1.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Spring?  They have a [module](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jmx.html) that does what you're describing with *@ManagedOperation* and *ManagedOperationParameter* annotations.  Otherwise, you're on your own to create the appropriate *javax.management.modelmbean.ModelMBeanOperationInfo* class when you're registering your object in JMX.

[JSR-255](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#jsr255) might address this in the future though.  See [this blog post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2007/08/defining_mbeans.html)